# wordpress custom template referencing external js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to use a custom template file in a wordpress site. The custom template seems to not be able to see the js. How do I fix this? It works fine at codepen.

http://codepen.io/redtailmedia/pen/BLzymO
This is the custom template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: customhome
*/
get_header(); ?>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GSAP SVG feDisplacementMap & feTurbulence element</title>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">       
  </head>    
  <body>      

<div id="box"> 
<svg class="mysvg" width="538" height="190" viewBox="0 0 600 200">
    <defs> 
        <filter id="turb">
            <feTurbulence id="turbwave" type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.03" numOctaves="2"
                result="turbulence_3" data-filterId="3" />
            <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence_3" scale="40" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <image id="img" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://www.redtailmediapei.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/redtailbanner.jpg" filter="url(#turb)" />
</svg>
</div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.9.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/customhome.js"></script>                   
  </body>
</html>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is the javascript:

```
TweenMax.to("#turbwave", 8, {
  attr:{"baseFrequency":0.01},
  repeat:-1,
  yoyo:true
});
```

And just to be thorough this is the css:

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  background:black;
  color:#FFF;
} 

a{
  color:#88CE02;
}

#box{
  position:relative;
  margin-top:40px;
}

svg #img{
  position:abosolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;  
  width:538px;  
  height:190px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure and the URL you're accessing when the JS can't be loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code its working:

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: customhome
 */
get_header();
?>
<div id="box"> 
    <svg class="mysvg" width="538" height="190" viewBox="0 0 600 200">
    <defs> 
    <filter id="turb">
        <feTurbulence id="turbwave" type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.03" numOctaves="2"
                      result="turbulence_3" data-filterId="3" />
        <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence_3" scale="40" />
    </filter>
    </defs>
    <image id="img" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://www.redtailmediapei.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/redtailbanner.jpg" filter="url(#turb)" />
    </svg>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.9.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script>
    TweenMax.to("#turbwave", 8, {
        attr: {"baseFrequency": 0.01},
        repeat: -1,
        yoyo: true
    });
</script> 
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

if you want to use customhome.js file then you have to use

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>
/js/customhome.js"></script>
```

js file put on js folder on theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the source file correctly. The best way to do this is using WordPress enqueue functions. You can add the following code in your functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpso39523464_enqueue_scripts' );

function wpso39523464_enqueue_scripts() {

    // You can also load the below js file on selected pages conditionally
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customhome.js', '', '', true );
}
```

If for any reason you want to avoid this technique, then in your above code you can slightly modify the script tag as below:

```
 <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/js/customhome.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the full path to the template directory in WordPress.

use

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js_foldername/filename.js
```

or

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js_foldername/filename.js
```

Put your file inside your JS folder inside activated theme.

It will work for you.